# Java and Selenium. Browser does not start

Tags: java, selenium

I have such problem.
I created project JavaFX. It use Selenium for work with HTML pages. In IDE (Intellij Idea) browser start success. If I compile a jar file and try to run it without IDE - browser does not start.
How can I fix it? 
Does Selenium work only in IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add webdriver to the project? Most IDE do not "copy paste" such files as .exe (like netbeans won't allow you to compile with driver). Probably forgot to copy webdriver, standalone server (if using)

Comment: I'm using org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.4.0.
In src folder of project exist geckodriver.exe. In IDE all work fine. I have problem when i try to run JAR-file without IDE - browser not start.

Comment: Oh! I understood! I need to add geckodriver.exe to filder where present JAR-file and all work fine/
Thank you!